# Prepared Statement fill list from database

Tags: java, sql, database

Hi I am trying to get all the values from my database and store them into a list.
Each row of values is put into an object and then stored in a list.

How should I do this, using a prepared statement or a statement?

Here is my current psuedo-code

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM People");

        List People = new List();

       while (st.next()) 
        {
         Person newPerson = new Person();
         newPerson.firstName = rset.getString("first_name");
         newPerson.lastName  = rset.getString("last_name");
         newPerson.email     = rset.getString("email");
         People.add(newPerson);
          }
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of both classes, or read the official JDBC tutorial? Why do you think using a prepared statement would be useful in this case? And also, why do you use a `List` and not a `List<Person>`? Why don't you at least try to compile your code before posting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking:

1. application start -> Open Connection
2. on some methods open stattement and fecth results set
3. close stmt (or resuse it) and close resultset (if error close)
4. application stop -> Close Connection

To manage these resources it is a little there are differcnces between java 6 and java 7.

### Java 6

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr,
                pwd);

            //.....

        PreparedStatement st=null;
        ResultSet rset=null;
        try {
            st = connection
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT first_name,last_name,email FROM People");

            List<Person> peoples = new ArrayList<Person>();

            rset = st.executeQuery();

            while (rset.next()) {
                Person newPerson = new Person();
                newPerson.firstName = rset.getString("first_name");
                newPerson.lastName = rset.getString("last_name");
                newPerson.email = rset.getString("email");
                peoples.add(newPerson);
            }

        } finally {

            try {
                rset.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                st.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

### Java 7

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");
             //.....

    try (PreparedStatement st = connection
            .prepareStatement("SELECT first_name,last_name,email FROM People")) {

        List<Person> peoples = new ArrayList<>(); // but should be new ArrayList<Person>();

        try (ResultSet rset = st.executeQuery()) {

            while (rset.next()) {
                Person newPerson = new Person();
                newPerson.firstName = rset.getString("first_name");
                newPerson.lastName = rset.getString("last_name");
                newPerson.email = rset.getString("email");
                peoples.add(newPerson);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note**: I didn't mange the connection since it is normally open and close when the application start end stop.

**Note**: the diamond <> java 7 way

Answer (score 0):

First get `ResultSet`

```
ResultSet rset = st.executeQuery();
```

and then

```
while(rset.next()){
```